# Undefined method 'visible_to' - Simple Rails website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm in the process of creating a very simple wiki based website where users can upgrade and downgrade their account. One of the perks of being a 'premium' member is the ability to create private wikis.

The issue I'm having is to do with this piece of code in my wikis_controller.rb:

```
def index
    @wiki = Wiki.visible_to(current_user)
    @wikis = policy_scope(Wiki)
end
```

When the code is written like that, I get an error message saying `'undefined method 'visible_to'`. But, if I comment out the first line in that method so that it looks like this:

```
def index
    #@wiki = Wiki.visible_to(current_user)
    @wikis = policy_scope(Wiki)
end
```

the user can see the wiki index, but they cannot see their private wikis.

Any ideas where I am going wrong? For reference, here is my wiki_policy.rb:

```
class WikiPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :record

  def initialize(user, record)
    @user = user
    @record = record
  end

  def update?
    user.present?
  end

  class Scope
     attr_reader :user, :scope

     def initialize(user, scope)
       @user = user
       @scope = scope
     end

     def resolve
       wikis = []
       if user.role == 'admin'
         wikis = scope.all # if the user is an admin, show them all the wikis
       elsif user.role == 'premium'
         all_wikis = scope.all
          all_wikis.each do |wiki|
           if !wiki.private? || wiki.user == user || wiki.users.include?(user)
             wikis << wiki # if the user is premium, only show them public wikis, or that private wikis they created, or private wikis they are a collaborator on
           end
         end
       else # this is the lowly standard user
         all_wikis = scope.all
         wikis = []
         all_wikis.each do |wiki|
            if !wiki.private? || wiki.users.include?(user)
             wikis << wiki # only show standard users public wikis and      private wikis they are a collaborator on
            end
          end
        end
        wikis # return the wikis array we've built up
      end
   end
end
```

and here is my application_policy.rb:

```
class ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :record

  def initialize(user, record)
     @user = user
    @record = record
  end

   def index?

   end

  def show?
    if user.standard?
      true
    else
      false
   end


  end

  def downgrade?
    if user.premium?
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end

  def create?
    if user.present?
      true
    else
      false
    end

  end

  def new?
    create?
  end


  def update?
    user.present?

  end

  def edit?
    update?
  end

  def destroy?
    if user.present? && user.admin? #|| record.user == user)
      true
    else
      false
    end

  end

  def scope
    Pundit.policy_scope!(user, record.class)
  end

  class Scope
    attr_reader :user, :scope

    def initialize(user, scope)
      @user = user
      @scope = scope
    end

    def resolve
      scope
    end
  end
end
```

Many Thanks.

Comment: Your error says the `visible_to` method does not exist. And low and behold, there is no such function in the code that you've included here. Maybe you should add the code for the `Wiki` class.

Comment: True. But even when I do add a 'visible_to' method to Wiki controller, I still pick up the same error message.

Answer (score 2):

> But even when I do add a 'visible_to' method to Wiki controller, I still pick up the same error message.

Without seeing your code I can't be certain but I am 95% sure your problem is that you're defining an **instance method** when you mean to define a **class method**.

You are probably doing this:

```
class Wiki
  # instance method
  def visible_to test
    puts test
  end
 end
```

Which would allow you to call the function like **instance method**:

```
irb(main):018:0> Wiki.new.visible_to "hello world"
  # hello world
irb(main):007:0> Wiki.visible_to "hello world"
  # NoMethodError: undefined method `visible_to' for Wiki:Class
```

But since you are actually calling the function like a **class method**:

```
Wiki.visible_to(current_user)
```

You need to define your method like this:

```
class Wiki
  # class method
  def self.visible_to test
    puts test
  end
 end
```

Now you can call the **class method**:

```
irb(main):024:0> Wiki.visible_to "hello world"
  # hello world
irb(main):007:0> Wiki.new.visible_to "hello world"
  # NoMethodError: undefined method `visible_to' for #<Wiki:0x00000001d16a68>
```

[Read more here!](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/)